# jQuery: Optional datepicker-field?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have a field like this:

```
<input name=devtime class=devtime>
```

and jQuery like this:

```
<script>$(".devtime").datepicker();</script>
```

If a user click inside the field (or it gets the focus) the datepicker appears.

How can i change the code so the users also can enter normal text and not just digits and numbers?

I'm looking for a common text field with "a datepicker option".

Thanks!

Comment: The issue with allowing text entry is a datetime field is that it opens up a lot of issues for validation. I'm not saying that it's impossible, or that there isn't a plugin which will allow this, just that it's a lot of work for a small gain.

Comment: you can use bootstrap date picker for the same when you click on icon date picker will appear else you can text in the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker has the constrainInput option:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput

This is true by default but if false you can put what you want in input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap date picker for the same when you click on icon date picker will appear else you can text in the text box.

[Reference Link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Note :- This is not advisable to use like this but this can be fulfil your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your markup with the below code

```
<input type="text" class="devtime">
```